# Rotate text ange in plotly bar chart

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a way to rotate the text labels over the bars (`20,14,23`) to  90 degrees ?

```
library(plotly)

x <- c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C')
y <- c(20, 14, 23)
text <- c('27% market share', '24% market share', '19% market share')
data <- data.frame(x, y, text)

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'bar',
               text = y, textposition = 'outside',
               marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                             line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5)))
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "January 2013 Sales Report",
                      xaxis = list(title = ""),
                      yaxis = list(title = ""))

fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `textangle` argument inside the `plot_ly` function.

```
fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'bar',
               text = y, textposition = 'outside',
               # rotate label
               textangle = 90,
               marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                             line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5)))
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "January 2013 Sales Report",
                      xaxis = list(title = ""),
                      yaxis = list(title = ""))

fig
```

[image]